Python Polars: Number of Rows since last value within a group
Given a polars DataFrame
data = pl.DataFrame({"user_id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], "login": [False, True, False, False, False, True]})
How could I add a column which adds the number of rows since the user last logged in, with any rows before a login for that user being set to None?
Example output for the above data is
[None, 0, 1, None, None, 0]
I tried adapting the answers from here, but cannot get it working with groups

You could subtract the row number of the previous login.
(df.with_row_index()
   .with_columns(distance = 
      pl.col.index - pl.when("login").then("index").forward_fill().over("user_id")
   )
)

shape: (6, 4)
┌───────┬─────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ index ┆ user_id ┆ login ┆ distance │
│ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ u32   ┆ i64     ┆ bool  ┆ u32      │
╞═══════╪═════════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 1       ┆ false ┆ null     │
│ 1     ┆ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 0        │
│ 2     ┆ 1       ┆ false ┆ 1        │
│ 3     ┆ 2       ┆ false ┆ null     │
│ 4     ┆ 2       ┆ false ┆ null     │
│ 5     ┆ 2       ┆ true  ┆ 0        │
└───────┴─────────┴───────┴──────────┘

If the data is unsorted, you can use .int_range() as the row number instead.
df.with_columns(distance =
   pl.int_range(pl.len()).over("user_id") 
   - pl.when("login").then(pl.int_range(pl.len())).forward_fill().over("user_id")
)

Details
(df.with_row_index()
   .with_columns(
      new_index  = pl.when("login").then("index"),
      last_index = pl.when("login").then("index").forward_fill(),
      last_index_groupwise = pl.when("login").then("index").forward_fill().over("user_id")
   )
)

shape: (6, 6)
┌───────┬─────────┬───────┬───────────┬────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ index ┆ user_id ┆ login ┆ new_index ┆ last_index ┆ last_index_groupwise │
│ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---                  │
│ u32   ┆ i64     ┆ bool  ┆ u32       ┆ u32        ┆ u32                  │
╞═══════╪═════════╪═══════╪═══════════╪════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 1       ┆ false ┆ null      ┆ null       ┆ null                 │
│ 1     ┆ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 1         ┆ 1          ┆ 1                    │
│ 2     ┆ 1       ┆ false ┆ null      ┆ 1          ┆ 1                    │
│ 3     ┆ 2       ┆ false ┆ null      ┆ 1          ┆ null                 │
│ 4     ┆ 2       ┆ false ┆ null      ┆ 1          ┆ null                 │
│ 5     ┆ 2       ┆ true  ┆ 5         ┆ 5          ┆ 5                    │
└───────┴─────────┴───────┴───────────┴────────────┴──────────────────────┘


when/then to create the null/non-null sequence
.forward_fill() to bring the previous value forward
.over() to make it a groupwise operation


that's a good one, forward_fill() follows the logic of that task nicely.

Thank you!! This answer works well when the user_ids are sorted, @RomanPekar your solution works even when they are not sorted

@cdkdrf You can use .int_range() instead for unsorted - it's just a little more verbose, I've added an example.

Thank! Would you be able to add an example how i might add another column for the amount of rows until a user next logs in? I tried playing around with it and using backward_fill() but can't get it working

@cdkdrf Maybe you can add a new question - it's a bit different.

Your example is a bit limited. What should happen if there're >1 logins for one user? You said that numbers should be increasing after last login, and before first login they should be None, but what should happen between first login and last login?
I assume that that you want to reset count on each login, so if I extend your input DataFrame:
data = pl.DataFrame({
    "user_id": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    "login": [False, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False]
})

┌─────────┬───────┐
│ user_id ┆ login │
│ ---     ┆ ---   │
│ i64     ┆ bool  │
╞═════════╪═══════╡
│ 1       ┆ false │
│ 1       ┆ true  │
│ 1       ┆ false │
│ 1       ┆ false │
│ 1       ┆ true  │
│ 2       ┆ false │
│ 2       ┆ false │
│ 2       ┆ false │
│ 2       ┆ true  │
│ 2       ┆ false │
└─────────┴───────┘

Then I'd expect result to look like:
┌─────────┬───────┬──────┐
│ user_id ┆ login ┆ res  │
│ ---     ┆ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ i64     ┆ bool  ┆ u32  │
╞═════════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ 1       ┆ false ┆ null │
│ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 0    │
│ 1       ┆ false ┆ 1    │
│ 1       ┆ false ┆ 2    │
│ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 0    │
│ 2       ┆ false ┆ null │
│ 2       ┆ false ┆ null │
│ 2       ┆ false ┆ null │
│ 2       ┆ true  ┆ 0    │
│ 2       ┆ false ┆ 1    │
└─────────┴───────┴──────┘

In this case you can use Expr.cum_count() over  Expr.cum_sum(), partitioned by user_id via Expr.over():
(
    data
    .with_columns(
        res = pl.col('login').cum_sum().over('user_id'),
    ).with_columns(
        pl.when('login').then(pl.col('res').cum_count().over('user_id', 'res') - 1),
    )
)

┌─────────┬───────┬──────┐
│ user_id ┆ login ┆ res  │
│ ---     ┆ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ i64     ┆ bool  ┆ u32  │
╞═════════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ 1       ┆ false ┆ null │
│ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 0    │
│ 1       ┆ false ┆ 1    │
│ 1       ┆ false ┆ 2    │
│ 1       ┆ true  ┆ 0    │
│ 2       ┆ false ┆ null │
│ 2       ┆ false ┆ null │
│ 2       ┆ false ┆ null │
│ 2       ┆ true  ┆ 0    │
│ 2       ┆ false ┆ 1    │
└─────────┴───────┴──────┘

